# Facebook 'like' button

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

Is it possible to have the very simple facebook like button, and a count (like they use for sharing content) when adding a button to like a facebook page?

I want to keep it nice and condensed, but the code offered by facebook included a title and a thumbnail.

---

**Edit**
To make it clear, I am looking for a 'become a fan of my facebook page' rather than a 'please share this page with your mates' button.

Comment: have you tried: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ and just selecting layout style: button_count.. seems to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [like box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is your only option for this, but as you say, it's styled slightly different to a standard like button. This is by design and can't be overridden.